# KeyError with Python dictionary from API

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I call a specific list with items in a dictionary? I want to use the key `name`, and output `Richmond`, in the `station` list. A tutorial I was using is outdated, so the best I could manage was this loop that printed the keys and items:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key, value)
```

That revealed the two outermost keys (`?xml` and `root`), but there are nested dictionaries I would like to access.

What I would like:

```
for item in data['station']
    print(item['name'])

>>> Richmond
```

Instead I get `KeyError` with `station`. Seeing as how `?xml` and `root` are the keys identified with the loop, I'm presuming I need a nested loop, first going through the `root` key, and then accessing `station`, and then using the key `name` to print `Richmond`.

The API result:

```
{
    "?xml": {
        "@version": "1.0",
        "@encoding": "utf-8"
    },
    "root": {
        "@id": "1",
        "uri": {
            "#cdata-section": "http://api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=RICH&json=y"
        },
        "date": "10/14/2017",
        "time": "07:50:17 PM PDT",
        "station": [{
            "name": "Richmond",
            "abbr": "RICH",
            "etd": [{
                "destination": "Warm Springs",
                "abbreviation": "WARM",
                "limited": "0",
                "estimate": [{
                    "minutes": "4",
                    "platform": "2",
                    "direction": "South",
                    "length": "6",
                    "color": "ORANGE",
                    "hexcolor": "#ff9933",
                    "bikeflag": "1",
                    "delay": "0"
                }, {
                    "minutes": "24",
                    "platform": "2",
                    "direction": "South",
                    "length": "6",
                    "color": "ORANGE",
                    "hexcolor": "#ff9933",
                    "bikeflag": "1",
                    "delay": "0"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        "message": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `for d in data['root']['station']: print d['name']`

Comment: Just did, and it worked! So, to get to sub-dicts nested in there, I need to have the key and list categorized. Got it!

Comment: So what if I want to access "etd", would I just add ['etd'] ? Doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `data['root']['station'][0]['etd']` for the first one in the 'station' list... 'name'  and 'etd' are keys in the same dict, so you'd have to replace one by the other.

Comment: Ah, right! I think i got it from here, appreciate the help!